# Send Email using smtp server from iphone using phonegap plugin

Tags: iphone, email, cordova, plugins, smtp

I have searched for email sending from iphone using smtp server but I just find the Email composing and send email plugin. Need Plugin for sending mail without composing mail.

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1202#1202 check out this link

Comment: Do you need to use SMTP or could you use a more web-friendly service like mailchimp for this? Then you wouldn't need a plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax post request to a php page in the server that does the email sending.. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677288