# SMTP Email is not sending on iPhone cordova WebApp, working in browser?

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I have a little problem with an iOS cordova Webapp and PHP. The code below works perfectly on the computer(Xampp):

```
<?php
require 'lib/sendMail.php';
require '../php/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$sendMail =  new sendMail();


$mail->isSMTP();                                    
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'ex@ex.de';             
$mail->Password = 'expw';                       
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         
$mail->Port = 587;                                    

$mail->From = 'ex@ex.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress($_POST['termin']['cityemail']);  

$mail->isHTML(true);                                

$mail->Subject = 'ex';
$mail->Body    = $sendMail->getMessage($_POST);
$mail->AltBody = $sendMail->getMessage($_POST);

if(!$mail->send()) {
    print 'Message could not be sent.';
    print 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    print 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

Note: I am using PhpMailer to send mails via the phone.

The problem is, that the phone is going crazy. Everything after "->" is ignored or something. This is how the screen looks after submitting the form:
[image: screen from iPhone]

How can this happen? The email is sending successfully on the browser.

The device is iPhone 5S 16GB with iOS 8.1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, it is php and runs on a web-server, not in the browser nor on an iPhone.

Comment: Maybe should have added that it is about an iOS Web app

Comment: You are opening this page in safari browser ?

Comment: It is not a page, it's a cordova Web App

Comment: you can only execute javascript,html,css in cordova web app. Php code needs a webserver.

Comment: Cordova does not support PHP, it HTML5, CSS and javascript with some native bindings.

Comment: So there is no way to get php working on cordova?

Comment: On your desktop you must be accessing it via a webserver (LAMP, XAMPP)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using XAMPP. Is there any way to get it working on the iPhone? Or could you tell me if there is another way to send an email via a WebApp? I havent found another solution than SMTP.

Comment: Probably some solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454294/can-i-send-email-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've got a working solution. Simply put your php files on a server, make an ajax call with type = " post " and there you go. Example code below(I'm using jQuery validation plugin) :

```
$("#Formular").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : 'http://yoururl.de/file.php',
                type: "POST",
                data : dataString,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    $('body').html(data);
                }
            });
        },
        rules: {
            'phone': {
                required: false,
                phoneDE: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'phone': {
                required: "Bitte gültige Telefonnummer eingeben"
            }
        }
    });
```